# Timer Subtracting One More Every Time

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a game timer which runs the time for the whole game. It works the first time, but when I go back to that view to play again it subtracts 2 every second. And the next time 3 and so on.

```
var masterTimer: NSTimer? = nil
```

And then in the viewDidLoad I have:

```
self.masterTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "fulltime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Here is the fulltime func:

```
func fulltime() {


    var FullTime = defaults.integerForKey("FullTime")
    var ScoreType = defaults.integerForKey("ScoreType")

    FullTime -= 1 //take a second away
    if (FullTime > 0)
    {
        TimerLabel.text = String(FullTime)
        defaults.setInteger(FullTime, forKey: "FullTime")
    }
    else
    {

        if ScoreType == 1 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score1")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 2 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score2")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 3 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score3")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 4 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score4")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 5 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score5")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 6 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score6")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 7 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score7")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 8 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score8")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else if ScoreType == 9 {
            defaults.setInteger(Score, forKey: "Score9")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }

        ScoreString = String(Score)
        ScoreLabel.text = ScoreString


        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HighScore") as HighScore
        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer you had before doesn't stop firing just because you reassigned a new timer to the masterTimer variable, or because the masterTimer variable no longer exists because the object to which it belongs dealloc'ed, you need to actually cancel it first and then start the new one.

Timers created with the scheduledTimerWith... method will be automatically added to the current run loop, and keep running independent of the fact that you keep a reference for them or not. So basically when you leave the screen it keeps going, unless you invalidate it.

You do so by calling the invalidate method on the timer.

```
if(self.masterTimer != nil){
    self.masterTimer!.invalidate()
}
```

You should make sure you call the invalidate method on the timer when it is no longer useful.
In your case that is possibly within the viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear methods of your viewController, during some method of your game logic like the current game ending or maybe in the dealloc method.